# if False not in pandas series of Boolean values

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, boolean, logic

I'm new to python and I have found tons of my questions have already been answered. In 7 years of coding various languages, I've never actually posted a question on here before, so I'm really stumped this time.

I'm using python 3.6

I have a pandas dataframe with a column that is just Boolean values. I have some code that I only want to execute if all of the rows in this column are True.

Elsewhere in my code I have used:

```
if True not in df.column:
```

to identify if not even a single row in df is True. This works fine.

But for some reason the converse does not work:

```
if False not in df.column:
```

to identify if all rows in df are True.

Even this returns False:

```
import pandas as pd

S = pd.Series([True, True, True])

print(False not in S)
```

But I have found that adding .values to the series works both ways:

```
import pandas as pd

S = pd.Series([True, True, True])

print(False not in S.values)
```

The other alternative I can think of is to loop through the column and use the OR operator to compare each row with a variable initialized as True. Then if the variable makes it all the way to the end as True, all must be true.

SO my question is: why does this return False?

```
import pandas as pd

S = pd.Series([True, True, True])

print(False not in S)
```

Comment: I believe DYZ provides the answer to your question, and GabrielA provides a solution for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`False not in S` is equivalent to `False not in S.index`. Since the first index element is 0 (which, in turn, is numerically equivalent to `False`), `False` is technically `in` `S`.

Comment: That was very helpful DYZ! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's not directly what you're asking but you can use .all() on a boolean series to determine if all values are true. Something like:

```
if df["column_name"].all():
    #do something
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `s.values` you are going to have access to a `numpy.array` version of the pandas Series/Dataframe.

Pandas provides a method called `isin` that is going to behave correctly, when calling `s.isin([False])`

Comment: Thanks rickyalbert, that's very helpful as well!

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I didn't know the answer to your main question, but I wanted to provide all the information I know :)